# List Box unable to fetch data until that sheet is open

Tags: vba, excel, userform

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim X As Integer
Dim ssheeet As Worksheet
Set ssheeet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
X = ListBox1.ListIndex
ListBox2.RowSource = ssheeet.Columns((X + 1) + 4).Address
End Sub
```

So here until i don't open sheet2 , the listbox2 is unable to fetch data from sheet2.But as per requirement user need to be on some other sheet .

While list box1 of same userform working well by fetching list from the same Sheet2 .thru following code ,

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ssheeet As Worksheet
Set ssheeet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet2!C:C"
```

Comment: do web search for `how to retrieve data from closed workbook`

Comment: which Sheets are each of the listboxes on?  Perhaps you need to specify the sheet if it's not active.

Comment: both are from sheet2 only on samw workbook .how to specify ?

Comment: sheets don't `open`, you can only activate or select them.... Your main problem comes from setting a sheet variable correctly, and then completely NOT using it ! Instead, you use a unreferenced `.address`(returns a string without the sheet or workbook info).
To be clear, i NEVER use rowsource. I use `Listbox1.List=RangeVar.value`, or `=ArrayVar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can set the List property like below...

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim ssheeet As Worksheet
    Set ssheeet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    X = ListBox1.ListIndex
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set Target = Intersect(.Columns((X + 1) + 4), .UsedRange)
        If Not Target Is Nothing Then
            ListBox2.List = Target.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i got run time error 70 and Permission Denied as error .

Comment: Clear the existing RowSource property in design mode if any set for ListBox2 and then it should work.

Comment: Are you using the proposed code exactly as it is? If yes, it should work without an issue. Also make sure that you are not trying to set RowSource property of ListBox2 anywhere else on the UserForm module in any other event.

Comment: no i am not doing anything for that listbox except you send and also used as it is.

Comment: @SunilPatra You're welcome! Glad it worked ultimately for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Range.Address(External:=True)` will return a fully qualified reference.

```
ListBox2.RowSource = ssheeet.Columns((X + 1) + 4).Address(External:=True)
```

Using `Application.Intersect` you can easily trim the `Range` to only include the used portion of the Column.

```
Dim Target As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set Target = Intersect(.Columns((x + 1) + 4), .UsedRange)
    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
        ListBox2.RowSource = Target.Address(External:=True)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in the line If Not taget Is Nothing Then, taget should be Target.